# How do you configure the IP address and port in App Engine Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How do you configure the IP address and port number in App Engine java environment? And how do you receive data on that IP and port?

Comment: Please provide details what data to import, and have you done some research

Comment: Which environment: standard or flexible environment?

Comment: standard environment

Comment: spelling, grammar

Answer (score 1):

This setup made for eclipse with app engine java sdk
In eclipse (Local)

1. First you need to install google app engine plugin
   https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download
2. Restart eclipse
3. open your google app engine project 
   (Eg: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-guestbook-multiphase/archive/master.zip)
4. Right click your project  google->App engine settings-->run config
   [image]
   [image]
5. In web application-> select your project then open server tab to config

[image]
 6. Run it in local 
[image]

Enjoy!!!

Comment: Not in local environment, i want firstly get IP address and than Listning a port on app Engine From multiple portable devices.

Comment: Hi sandeep negi, you are not mention local or global, so i thought my suggesion

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server

It says, that you can use server command options --address=... and --port=...